# Chromium loading on the tab lags

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 and Chromium 65.0.3325.181. Everything was good before the last update but after the update (updated chromium and Ubuntu base), Chromium loading on the tab lagging before showing up the content.

See the loading circle on the tab bar:

[image: Chrome tab loading lag]

1. Resolving host (no lag)
2. Connecting (no lag)
3. Waiting for URL (no lag)
4. When the content goes white and wait for the first real content (lag)
5. When the first real content fetched (no lag)

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?